# How to create a gas glow in (earth) atmosphere

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

In reading about ionized air-glow:  "Is it possible to generate a localized gas glow in a confined space, like a room/gym/warehouse/etc, in earth's "normal" atmosphere/mix?  Can this be selectively done, ionizing just the nitrogen or the argon and mercury?  From what I have read, achieving this effect appears to require containment and substantive energy input.  Does the ionized air-glow have properties that will harm surrounding materials should they make contact such as wood floor/painted walls/people?    And if not feasible, please, even a brief explanation as to why this is not currently achievable? ...thank you."

Comment: Hopefully you don't have much mercury floating around in your room...

Comment: So you're not talking about flourescent tube lighting?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to create a glow discharge at atmospheric pressure but it requires  high electric field strengths (as in a pair of flat electrodes very close together) or a highly asymmetric electrode layout (as in the case where one electrode is a sharp point). This is easy to do in small air gaps but not out in the open in a room.

The visible light thus produced comes mostly from nitrogen ionization and is deep blue in color.